# Regular Expression for not allowing two consecutive special characters

Tags: regex

What i am trying to do is to **not** allow *two consecutive special characters* like `&*` or `*$` or `&&`, but it should allow special characters in between strings like `Hello%Mr&`.

What i have tried so far:

```
^(([\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-])\2?(?!\2))+$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
^(?!.*[\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]{2}).*$
```

The idea is to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?!)`) to verify that nowhere in the string (`.*`) are there two consecutive *"special"* characters (`[...]{2}`). Afterwards, you just match the entire string (`.*`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
\A\W?(?>\w+\W)*\w*\z
```

or

```
\A[%/\\&?,';:!-]?(?>[^%/\\&?,';:!-]+[%/\\&?,';:!-])*[^%/\\&?,';:!-]*\z
```

or

```
\A[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]?(?>[\p{L}\p{N}\s]+[^\p{L}\p{N}\s])*[\p{L}\p{N}\s]*\z
```

or

```
\A[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]?(?>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+...
```

depending of what do you call a "special character".

Comment: Sorry, is there a way to combine into: ^(?!.*(.)\1{4})[a-zA-Z'&-]+([[:space:]][a-zA-Z'&-]+)*$